# jQuery click event requires double click to work

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, click

I actually got some problems with my script: indeed it needs 2 clicks to work in a click event. The script is this:

```
  $('td#td_new').live('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'add_hobby.php',
    data: { hobby: $('#ricerca_interests').val() }, 
     success: function(msg) {                         
        nuovo_hobby="<tr id='hobby' class='checked' selezionato='si'  hobby_id='"+msg+"' ><td id='hobby' width='179px'><div id='nome_hobby'>"+$('#ricerca_interests').val()+'</div></td></tr>';
        $(nuovo_hobby).appendTo("#interessilista");

         $('tr#new_hobby').hide().remove();


        },
    error: function() {alert("Error. Try later.");}
}); 

   });
```

Comment: What version of jQuery are you using?

Comment: Does it really take a second click, or do you just click a second time before the AJAX response is received?

Comment: And "work" means what exactly? What happens and what do you expect to happen? Please create a http://jsfiddle.net/ demo that reproduces the problem.

Comment: try binding the event using some other function (instead of .live().)
Maybe something like:
$('td#td_new').click(function(){...});

Or:
$('td#td_new').bind('click',function(){...});

Comment: I'm using jQuery 1.7.2 @AustinBrunkhorst .

Comment: It really take a second click, I've also tried with a console.log, it needs a second click to run the function @David

Comment: I've tried in jsfiddle.net but there the script works, so I think is something else in the code.. [Here](http://pastebin.com/cFVNJGPa)'s the whole page code, sorry for the confusion @FelixKling

Comment: I switched it in .on() @KhalidDabjan

Answer (score 0):

As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. you should Use .on() to attach event handlers.

it doesn't seems that your code generate something that can cause a second click need... but try changing-

`$('td#td_new').live('click', function() {`

to

`$(document).on('click','#td_new', function() {`

then open firebug or add a `console.log('something')` in the `success:` part - and make sure that the ajax request finishes as wanted and not continuing to run.

other then that we need some more code...

have fun.

**EDIT**:

I tried to understand what you are trying to do according to the code you upload, but 
there is noway to test it, so here are some insights for you:

1. Include your source scripts (jquery + UI etc) in the head section.
2. Remove jquery.min... source - you don't need it because you include the full script any way.
3. I recommend upgrading to jquery 1.9... you are using 1.7.2
4. When using same identifier over different elements you should use `class` not `id` to declare them.
5. I recommend you to attach the click event to the div `add_hobby` as a class and not to the `td`.

Here is a small demo of the usage of on() and appending code to your page:

[**jsfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k3QyU/)

Now feel free to direct me to your exact problem.

Comment: I switched in .on() but it still doesn't work, I've also tried to add a consoe.log('blabla') at the beginning of the function but nothing..Any ideas?

Comment: post some more code please... you are not attaching the event so the function doesn't fires... you may have an ID of element problem there make sure your button has `id="#td_new"`.

Comment: by the way - we use on() for dynamically added elements... is that your case? i really need some more code please...

Comment: [Here](http://pastebin.com/cFVNJGPa)'s all the page, sorry for the confusion and thanks a lot for the help!

Comment: It still doesn't work, did you read the code? Thanks.. @ShlomiHassid

Comment: @Giulio Colleluori - take a look at my edit according to the code given.

Comment: i really enjoy down-voting without any comment or reason... thanks