# JQuery click event needs double click

Tags: javascript, jquery

Before marking as a duplicate, I have looked at the following questions and nothing has worked for me.

[jQuery click event requires double click to work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17777228/jquery-click-event-requires-double-click-to-work)

[Click and double-click event firing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8596756/click-and-double-click-event-firing) (loosely realted)

I have a JQuery event that requires a single click in some instances and a double click in most others.

Please see the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/SimonPrice/6e9acbo6/5/

In this fiddle you will see an accurate representation of the data, the expend and collapse functions do not work so I have removed their functions from the javascript window to avoid distraction from popups \ alerts.

In the fiddle you will see a table with a nested table that has nested tables.  (Code I have inherited).

Using this code

```
$(document).ready(function () {

$(document).on('click', '.up', function () {
    shiftRow($(this));
});
$(document).on('click', '.down', function () {
    shiftRow($(this));
});

});
```

Which is the proposed answer from the first link I cannot get this to work and I am still having to double click.

I have also tried it on the document, table, tr and td elements as well as the class click event it self.

I need this to work on a single click and would be grateful if anyone can help me see the error that I am making.

Comment: You're trying to get the expand/collapse buttons to work, correct?

Comment: @freginold no, other side of the table, you will see a up and a down arrow...  ignore the expand \ collapse buttons. that works fine in the actual application, just not in the fiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've added additional log to your function:

```
function shiftRow(rowbObj) {
console.log("up or down arrow clicked");
var row = $(rowbObj).closest("tr");
console.log(row[0].rowIndex);
var thisTable = row.closest("table");
if ($(rowbObj).is(".up")) {
    if (row[0].rowIndex > 0) {
     console.log("current: "+row.text() + " prev: " +row.prev().text());
```

So it helped me to realize you have additional hidden TR for the row content (probably for expand) – (

```
<tr id="content_0_36000" class="content" style="display: none;">
```

)
So when you click once, you replace between the shown and the hidden, that’s why it seems like nothing happens

Comment: Good catch! On my side, what I found is that `$(this)` is sent to the function as `rowbObj`, and then used like `$(rowbObj)`, which isn't really good... Also, the `<a href="#" class="up">` is useless... The class up should be on the `<i>`... ;) +1

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette can you expand on why its not really good to do this? Can you provide an answer on what you found and how it would\shoudlbe done

Comment: with regards to the hidden row, yes, thats what I was originally supplied with that then holds the next nested table.. so yes, I see your point on this too